# ssrs stacked column chart percentage display

Tags: reporting-services, charts, percentage

-in Sql, my dataset is showing this:

```
   MonthName, Type, MonthNumber, YearNumber, Deals
   Feb        used      2          2015      40
   Feb        New       2          2015      30
   Mar        Used      3          2015      50
   Mar        New       3          2015      20
```

-In my stacked Column Chart:
Values: sum(Deals)
Category group: Monthname
SeriesGroup: Type

Sorry, I am not able to upload the picture. So, I am going to explain the chart.
-in the stacked column chart, I want to the bar showing the %:

```
the bar of Feb: 40/(40+30)=57%
           Feb: 30/(40+30)=43%    
the bar of Mar: 50/(50+20)=71%
           Mar: 20/(50+20)=29%
```

I did the expression in label date

=sum(Fields!Deals.Value)/Sum(Fields!Delas.Value, "DataSet1")
But the result was

```
the bar of Feb: 40/(40+30+50+20)=28%
           Feb: 30/(40+30+50+20)=21%    
the bar of Mar: 50/(40+30+50+20)=35%
           Mar: 20/(40+30+50+20)=14%
```

Can anyone help me to get 57%,43%,71%,29%    Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Properties -> Chart Series Label -> Format -> ##.#0\%

This will show the percentage symbol in a stack chart.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "dataset1" you have to use "Monthname" (Which is the catagory). This will give u the expected output.

Let me know if still ur facing some issues.

Comment: Yes, you are right! In my case, I do not need do any expression at all. What I did is  1) chose stacked percentage column chart  2) in the chart - Values: sum(Deals)
 -Category group: Monthname
- SeriesGroup: Type.   Then SSRS will generate bar with % of 57%,43%,71%,29%.   The reason I did not work it out was in the where clause of main dataset " where date >@startdate and date < @enddate". If I change it to "where date >=@startdate and date < =@enddate, the 57%,43%,71%,29%. showed in the bar. However, I do not understand why using >  instead of >= cause the problem.